# Same API routes for SPA and external users

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

Laravel 8 with [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum).

I plan to use the same API routes for SPA and external users. The problem is that Sanctum requires the `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` middleware to be added to the "api" middleware group which makes my API "stateful". It's fine for a SPA, but I'd like to keep it "stateless" for external calls with token authentication.

The simplest solution would be to separate SPA and external routes, with different middleware groups. Not  so elegant! Please advise something better :)

UPD: Decided to split routes

routes/api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->as('api.')->group(function () {
    require 'resources.php';
});
```

routes/spa.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->as('spa.')->group(function () {
    require 'resources.php';
});
```

routes/resources.php

```
Route::apiResources([
    'products' => 'Api\ProductController',
]);
```

App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->routes(function () {

       ....

        Route::prefix('spa')
            ->middleware('spa')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/spa.php'));
    });
}
```

App\Http\Kernel

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [

      ....
        
        // Stateless, external calls
        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        // SPA, stateful, internal use
        'spa' => [
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            'SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: you can use same api in SPA vuejs

Comment: Sure. But Sancrum SPA Authentication  makes API stateful, while Restful for external users must be stateless. I could use token authorization both for SPA and Rest, but i will need to issue tokens for every user.

Comment: create your token base login page i used like that only